# Error return values for struct in Cython?

Tags: cython

We can do this in Cython so that whenever the return value is -1, Cython generates a call to `PyErr_Occurred()`:

```
cdef int spam() except?-1:
```

However, what if the return type is a struct?

```
ctypedef struct A:
    double x
    double y

cdef A spam() except ?????
```

Say, I want to define an error value to be: `A(x=1, y=-1)`. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs this is probably not possible.

This note can be found at the end of the [Error return values](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values) section of `cython`'s docs

> Exception values can only declared for functions returning an integer, enum, float or pointer type, and the value must be a constant expression. Void functions can only use the except * form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify an error value, but you can let errors propagate by writing

```
cdef A spam() except *:
    [code that may raise exceptions]
```

which will implicitly use the `PyErr_Occurred` macro rather than the return value to determine whether an error occurred.